# Exporting raster values into ASCII file format?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, spatial-analyst, export, ascii

How do I get all pixel values of a time series NDVI image (raster) and export its values into an ASCII file?

Comment: Perhaps ASCII (.asc) isn't the format you want. The file format is header (6-8 lines) and then data (space delimited), one value per cell for each column and one line per row. You might do better with XYZ, this would make it easier to identify individual cells by X and Y. This I would do with GDAL_Translate -of XYZ <IN file> <out file>. It can also be done in arc by raster to point and then add xy coordinates. Open the DBF of the shape in Excel. Note this will not work for very large rasters as shape files have a maximum size.

Answer (score 1):

You can export a raster to ASCII in ArcGIS for Desktop using its [Raster to ASCII (Conversion)](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//001200000005000000) tool:

> Converts a raster dataset to an ASCII text file representing raster
>   data.

Comment: The youtube link is no longer available. Can you expand your answer to explain how can one export raster values to a data format Excel can read?

Comment: @AndreSilva I removed that part of the answer which had been edited in by another user.  I also focused the question some more.

Comment: It is a pity you removed the Excel part from this question; I guessed from [Q version 1](https://gis.stackexchange.com/revisions/93704/1) that it was more important than the ascii file, because it was written first (both in title and body). I found this Q trying fo find a duplicate for a recent asked question (https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/267126/basic-workflow-to-create-excel-data-from-raster-tiff-in-arcgis?noredirect=1#comment424431_267126). continues...

Comment: So I am little bit disappointed, because you are an arcgis consultant/expert; I was expecting you to expand your answer instead of simplifying it. Is it difficult to show an example about how this ASCII file would look like, and then, explaining the necessary steps to prepare it for Excel input? Let me know if you decide to improve your answer, I will upvote it. Tks.

Comment: @AndreSilva the original question had two questions. I only had time to answer one without further research and my interest is rarely raster data. That made my choice become to either close the question as too broad or focus it to a single question (for which there was an answer provided).  My preference is to have all questions open and answered which one question per question facilitates.